# Google script: email with answers given by a single user to a form compiled in google drive

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've created a form using google drive. 
In order to provide to answerers a summary of what they wrote I would like to send an email to each of them, using the email they insert in the form.

I think it is possible to do this installing a script in the spreadsheet of the form result that send an email every time a new row is recorded.

I've found (on this forum) the following script that is, unfortunately, an email alert with a modify in a certain spreadsheet.

```
function sendNotification() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
var recipients = "me@gmail.com";
var message = '';
if(cell.indexOf('G')!=-1){ 
message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
}
var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view     the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message:  «' + message + '»';
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);

};
```

And here is the help I need. The script sends an email to a single predefined address. Is it possible to let the script take the recipient email from a certain cell in the relevant row (for example the email is recorded in the col C of the spreadsheet) and send him a message that contains some text taken by other cells of the same row ( for example col D and E)?

Comment: Take a look at the on form submit trigger, there is an event that contains every information you need, including the row number and even the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the variables you defined in your code (sheet, row):

```js
//returns email address in column C
var recipient = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();

//returns values in column D and E
var info1 = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
var info2 = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
```

Please be aware that this is an 'expensive' way to get the values and you would better served getting all values as an array in one call and then referencing them by index, as below.

```js
//get all required values in one call
var values = sheet.getRange(row, 3, 1, 3).getValues();

//define variables using array index
var recipients = values[0];
var info1 = values[1];
var info2 = values[2];
```

Comment: You've been very kind. Thank you. I've modified the script as you wrote. Now it takes the email and the text from the row. But i think it takes the text in the active row (if the row is selected in the opened file). I'm not able to let the script send the email when a new row is compiled in the spreadsheet to the email written in the form...

Comment: Identifying the correct row was not in the scope of the original question! :) You can use `var row = sheet.getLastRow();` but be aware that if someone else submits a form (which I'm assuming is triggering your function) before your function completes there will be confusion. Coding around this can quickly become complex.

Comment: Thank you I will try before giving up! :-) sorry for my English !